# Oracle Import Dump

Tags: oracle, import

After system failure I have bought a new server and now Im trying to recreate the oracle database I had. I have a dump file which was made with the command exp and full=y. So can I restore the full database from this dump? If yes how?

Oracle 11g
Windows server 2003

Comment: There's a dba.stackexchange.com sister site that may give you better guidance on Oracle matters.

Comment: thx I submited the question there.

Comment: @Alexk Do not cross-post; if you want a Q moved to another site, Flag it and we'll move it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
imp file=blabla.dmp username/password
```

or

```
imp file=impfile.dmp fromuser=xy touser=xy
```

if you are sysdba

But!!!: you have to have the same(!) version (major + cpu)
And you have to have created the users and tablespaces before

Comment: I want to add that if you have everything in place... installed correct oracle version and your instance is working the import is going to be easy. So dont worry...

Comment: The versions are the same and i am dba. Shouldnt I use the full=y command in imp? In what state should the DB in for the imp?

Comment: The DB should be in normal state (mounted, connected and open). Currently I dont have an oracle box at hands but I dont remember a full parameter on imp. If there is any just have a look in the doc. I think i never needed it for restoring. I used exp/imp quite a lot for creating duplicate databases a long time ago and dump files are our basis for backup too.

Comment: ok, had a short look at the doc. seems that full=y on imp tells the process to recreate the tablespaces and discard present data. So give it a try...

Comment: Users and tablespaces created ok but I got tons of specific errors, 2 to be exact ORA-00001 and ORA-02195.

Comment: at least I have the tablespaces and the users now, so I will create then manually and retry the import.

Comment: Hm, 02195 means "ora-02195 attempt to create PERMANENT object in temporary tablespace." My first guess: something with creation of the users went wrong - check the default tablespace of the users in the log. Perhaps they are wrong. Otherwise I would skip the "full=y"

Comment: The issue with the ora-02195 was solved by precreating the tablespaces. The ORA-00001 was not exactly an issue since it is only duplicate entries. So everything went well. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You do not need the same version or cpu platform, data migration is supported across both versions and platforms! You should however run the exp and imp using the highest version, eg. if you want to migrate data from 10g to 11g, you should use the 11g version of the utilities.